Information sharing between two kubernetes services
I have 2 REST API services running on the same kubernetes cluster- service A and service B. Service A needs some information stored by service B in etcd. What is the best way to fetch that information?
I am evaluating 3 options-

Service A invokes a service B REST API to get this required information - since the services are already REST API servers, this is easy.

Service A invokes a service B gRPC API to get this information - since the services are running on the same cluster, gRPC will be more efficient than REST API.

Service A directly accesses the information updated by service B in etcd - can this be done?



Typical microservices practice is that one service should never directly access another service's data store.  But otherwise, choice of gRPC vs. plain HTTP vs. some other protocol is up to your local needs and experience and existing patterns.

You said, service B exposes REST Api. It is better to consume serviceB api from Service A and get the required data as a response from Service B
